# Error when selecting data from information_schema table

Tags: php, pdo

```
SELECT CARDINALITY FROM `information_schema` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dicasecr_db1' LIMIT 1
```

I Run this, but I get FALSE as response, and there is this row, with CARINALITY = 2.
Any idea why?

My intention is use the statistics to don't need to run this query instead:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `dicasecr_db1`
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, I just thougth `information_schema` were a table, and it's a database, so, the correct query works, and it's:

```
SELECT CARDINALITY FROM `information_schema`.`STATISTICS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dicasecr_db1' LIMIT 1
```

Sorry for the mess.